# How to keep protractor running?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, protractor

I'm trying to access Db in protractor tests using a sql server driver for NodeJs (protractor is a nodejs application so this is no problem)

The idea is to check Db data in our e2e tests:

- We can check whether some hidden things are written correctly in the Db that cannot be seen on the UI (e.x Logs,..)
- We can isolate features in our e2e testing: we don't rely on another feature to display the data to check whether the feature writing the data works correctly.

The problem I'm having is whenever protractor finishes interacting with the browser, it will terminate. Therefore, my code to access the Db cannot verify the data retrieved (e.x `expect(dataFromDb).toEqual('foo'))` because requests to Db are asynchronous in NodeJs.

At the time when I retrieve the data via the callback, protractor has been terminated.

It looks to me that protractor is only aware of web browser promises and terminates when there are no outstanding browser promises.

Is there any solution to keeping protractor alive so that I can verify my Db data? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: protractor should be considered as a real tester in real world. In real world, a tester would open a browser, test it and then goes to the Db to check the data. Therefore, protractor should be designed with this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind.

1) `expect(dataFromDb).toEqual('foo'))`: Protractor wrapped `expect` to understand promises. However, it only understands `webdriver.promise` (i.e. no $q or any other promise). If you want to make assertions against non webdriver promises, you have to resolve the promise yourself like:

```
dataFromDb.then(function(resolvedData) {
  expect(resolvedData).toEqual('foo')
})
```

2) Protractor does not "terminate". Protractor only helps you kick off your test using another test framework (i.e. jasmine, mocha); once it does that it is only a library of tools (i.e. locators, waitForAngular, etc) that you run on top of that test framework. It's that other framework you must prevent from terminating. I don't know what framework you're using, but I'll use jasmine as an example:

```
it('call db', function(done) { //notice the inclusion of `done`
  browser.get('something'); //this is protractor 
  element(by.xyz).click(); //this is protractor

  var data = queryDatabase(); // you must tell jasmine to wait for this.
  data.then(function(resolvedData) {
    expect(resolvedData).toBe('foo');
    done(); // tell jasmine you're done. 
  })
})
```

Side note, protractor patched jasmine `it` to wait for webdriver commands to finish (just like how it patched `expect`) for user's convenience. However, if you don't use webdriver's promise you need to tell `it` when the test is done via the `done` callback